# Word document showing content with special characters ¶

Tags: microsoft-word

Special characters such as ¶ are showing up in my Word document (see image below)

[image: Word doc]

How do I remove these special characters?

Comment: That's calls "Show Formatting" mode.  Note also the arrows showing where indents are in your billeted list.

Answer (score 4):

Click the `¶` button on the `Home menu`, looks like you've enabled paragraph marker.

Answer (score 1):

It is not special characters, it is the paragraph markers, there is a setting to show them or not

Answer (score 1):

Office 2007 solution:

1. Click the Office button
2. From the Office menu, click the Word Options button
3. Click the Display button
4. In the Display window, look for the Always Show These Formatting Marks on the Screen section.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-show-nonprinting-characters-in-word-2007.navId-323086.html

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.