# Microsoft Word, Powerpoint, Excel adding unnecessary letters while opening a file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

Downloaded and opening a word file from web add the this kind of formatting at the end of each paragraph. What is the reason?

Here is the image to let you know the problem

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mub7hukxjilge8d/Fullscreen%20capture%201312015%20125135%20PM.bmp.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The paragraph markers have been covered on this site many times. http://superuser.com/questions/198080/word-document-showing-content-with-special-characters/198083?s=1|0.8176#198083 If there are other things , then you need to edit your question to be completly clear about everything.

Comment: @Psycogeek: please place your comment as an answer or flag as duplicate or report for deletion.